# Is this short summary of phenomenology accurate?

Tags: ethics, ontology, phenomenology

"Classical, pure phenomenology aims to comprehend “those structures of experience and understanding that permit different types of beings to show themselves as what they are.” It does this by rejecting the idea that the subject, qua experiencer, is conceptually distinct from that which it experiences. (p. 74) "

I am writing about phenomenology as a method by which we can understand mental health problems, and I'm on the section of the paper where I do a quick 'here's the contemporary thought, and here's the concept I'm going to use.' - is the sentence above ok?? I've talked about how phenomenology isn't just a way of describing things accurately, but a study of the structures of experience. (Basing this all on Husserlian concepts)

Thank you in advance for your insight!! xxx

Comment: Do you have a reference for the quoted text? I don't know much about phenomenology, but this might be something worth reading.  Welcome to Philosophy!

Comment: Phenomenology is closely associated Psychology, and it is almost as diverse... If you want more than "Yes, this summary will serve your purpose" you may elicit better responses if you could elaborate a bit more on your references and intention: Which phenomenologists would you like to quote or credit?

Comment: "permit different types of beings to show themselves as what they are" is too cryptic without a paragraph of explanations, and why only "beings"? It was "*back to the **things** themselves*", including but not limited to beings. You can quote something from [Merleau-Ponty's What is Phenomenology](https://www.jstor.org/stable/24456652), for example.

Comment: Obviously, no description that short is possibly accurate. I would be careful to include at least a short discussion/qualification for any graded text since otherwise, it would surely solicit negative impact on the grading. Other than that, I would think that Conifold's point about "back to the things (in) themselves" is spot on. It is about structures of the *things* showing themselves, which has transcendental character for the late Husserl and is only insofar "neither of object (appearance/phenomenon) nor subject".

Comment: @FrankHubeny it's just literally a sentence from the essay I'm writing! The bit in quotation marks is from Dan Zahavi Subjectivity and Selfhood - it's very good I highly recommend it.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking Sorry, I wasn't clear, that's not my entire description, just a remark about one of the aims of phenomenology in the tradition of Husserl, Merleau-Ponty and their modern commentators, as opposed to the description that can surface in Philosophy of mind that phenomenology is simply a method in which to describe things properly.

Comment: @Conifold I can't really change that quote as it is a direct pull from Dan Zahavi's subjectivity and selfhood, he's talking about beings that have a selfhood, as opposed to our phenomenological experience of objects if that makes sense? But thank you for the link, I think I will return to Merleau-Ponty for the structures of experience that I need :)

Comment: @Christo Yesss I completely agree, I think I needed to add the full paragraph that that sentence was in. I was just having a crisis of confidence I think... I want reassurance that the aim of classical phenomenology is to study the structures of experience, to try and understand how experiences can happen in the first place. But I think I have answered my own question in responding to my kind responders. Thank you for the advice :)

Comment: It strikes me that phenomenology has a lot of (unrealized) potential for the mental health field. Husserl is the locus classicus for this since he basically invented the subject. His rendering of it in "Cartesian Meditations" and "Phenomenology" strikes me as more on point as a study of consciousness itself than later developments and renderings by Heidegger, Sartre, Merleau-Ponty & Co. Anglo-American psychology of late seems to me to have become way too obsessed with physicalist approaches to mind such as those afforded by neurophysiology. The mind (let alone consciousness) is not the brain.